# One More Time Around

Tags: riddle, rhyme

First is a dive; not much, but it's cheap
Next is the cache for society's keep
Another dive follows; it's much like the first
Please not the next one; of all, it's the worst
The next is for readers, they'll chew and they'll chew
After that, east; you're light but you're blue
The next's rather risky; there's some good at least
Then two more are stately, and much like the east
Next comes the crooks while they go round the bend
Then comes a saintly and violet friend
But I got the highest, as high as one gets!
I now have to go there, **so tell me: what's next?**

*Please provide an explanation of the clues along with your answer. ;)*

Comment: Two ideas come to mind: a) letterplay (Aggie Kidd style: "first is a dive" = D and so on) and b) fiction novels (maybe the "first", "next", etc. are books in a series?)

Comment: @randal'thor That would be a 13 letters word (if I counted well), but I really can't get which letter is "violet"...as for fiction riddles, it might be so, I don't know, not my field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> Electric Company.
>  You rolled double 6's for your opening roll on a game of Monopoly.

First is a dive; not much, but it's cheap

> Mediterranean Avenue:  The cheapest property on the board, named after the Mediterranean Sea, where you can dive.

Next is the cache for society's keep

> Community Chest

Another dive follows; it's much like the first

> Baltic Avenue:  In the same set (dark purple) as Mediterranean; it's also named after a body of water that you can dive in, the Baltic Sea.

Please not the next one; of all, it's the worst

> Luxury tax:  Pay 10% or $200 (in the U.S. at least)

The next is for readers, they'll chew and they'll chew

> Reading Railroad:  "Chew" sounds like a train: "Choo choo"

After that, east; you're light but you're blue

> Oriental Avenue:  "Oriental" means "eastern".  Part of the light blue set.

The next's rather risky; there's some good at least

> Chance:  Could have a positive or negative outcome.

Then two more are stately, and much like the east

> Vermont and Connecticut Avenues:  Both part of the light blue set as well, named after U.S. States.

Next comes the crooks while they go round the bend

> Jail:  On the corner, while you're going "round the bend" is where the "crooks" are.

Then comes a saintly and violet friend

> St. Charles Place:  Starts with the word "Saint"; part of the light purple (violet) set

But I got the highest, as high as one gets!

> I rolled a 12 right off the bat; you can't roll higher than that in Monopoly.

I now have to go there, **so tell me: what's next?**

> The next property on the board is Electric Company, the 12th space from "Go".

Comment: I'll give you the checkmark, but you need to provide an explanation of the clues along with the answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Baltic and Mediterranean are bodies of water, hence the term dive, community chest is a cache for society's keep. income tax is the worst (unless you think of going to jail as worse than that), reading railroad is where trains go choo choo, oriental avenue is light blue, chance is next but is sometimes a good card. Vermont and Connecticut are in the same group and are named after states. the next square is the jail, but if you land on it you're "just visiting" and don't have to stay. next is the purple st. charles' place, and after that, is the electric company, the 12th position.

Comment: Is this weird stuff the US-style Monopoly board? :-o The one I'm used to has London streets and looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E4MmK.jpg). I think all the clues work for that as well except the "for readers" clue.

Comment: Correct. Google images should be able to provide you with a picture that you can compare it to.

Comment: All correct. It's an interesting observation about "dive" referring to the bodies of water. I was actually using it in the slang sense of a "run down or cheap property". For example, a dirty bar or a cheap motel are often called "dives". The dark purples are the roach motel properties of the Monopoly world.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a Monopoly board, the first two properties being the cheapest (a dive being a badly maintained hotel) and they're separated by the community chest.

Reference to jail where there are crooks around the bend as it's a corner square.

Presumably what's next is to pass go and collect £200?

Comment: You were so close.

Comment: It's a good job that dive also means run down hotel because the first two properties on a British Monopoly board are Old Kent Road and Whitechapel Road.  That may also explain why I didn't get all of the other references.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I would have been able to figure out a british version of the riddle.